# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Мы ехали почти всю дорогу разговаривая"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Подскажите, нужна ли запятая в этом предложении: "Мы ехали почти всю дорогу разговаривая".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужна. Мы ехали, почти всю дорогу разговаривая. (Мы ехали и разговаривали). Предложение осложнено деепричастным оборотом, который обозначает добавочное действие.  *Разговаривая (как долго?) почти всю дорогу*. Инверсия в данном случае не влияет на постановку запятой.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!